# No sound output on Arch linux after suspend or some time of inactivity

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

Lately, I have encountered some issues with my Built-in audio device. I cannot play any sound for some reason after waking up from the suspended state or after some time of inactivity (I mean no apps that produce some sound output for >1 min or so).
For example, a video on youtube is loaded but doesn't start playing.

I tried to reload PulseAudio using `/usr/bin/pasuspender /bin/true` but this doesn't work.

### What works

I found the temporal solution to change the configuration profile every time this issue appears.

For instance, my default profile is 'Analog Stereo Duplex'. I change the profile to another and then apply 'Analog Stereo Duplex' back. And the sound now works fine.

What can be the right permanent solution for this case?

Comment: Yeah, if you're using 5.17.0 or newer please report a bug to bugzilla.kernel.org

Comment: Is this for an HDMI sound output?

Comment: @dirkt no, this is not for an hdmi sound output. i mentioned that this is for built-in audio